# How to get results from Oracle Trigger and act accordingly

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

i have created a after update trigger for a table in my database, that when a value is modified in a specific column, it also updates a same table from another database. My question is, how can i check if the results are 0 (that means such row does not exists in the 2nd database, and 1 that the row exists and its updated) and act accordingly? i want if i get 0 that means such primary key does not exist, to create it in the 2nd database. Here is my ORACLE trigger code:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_BIOGR 
AFTER UPDATE OF ID_PATIENTS,NAME,SNAME,GENDER,DATE_BORN,COUNTRY,CITY,BLOODTYPE,FATHER_ID,MOTHER_ID,FATHER_NAME,FATHER_LASTNAME,MOTHER_FIRSTNAME,MOTHER_LASTNAME,TIL,E_MAIL ON BIOGR 
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW

   DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

    UPDATE PERSONAL_RECORD.BIOGR SET
    ID = :NEW.ID_PATIENTS, NAME = :NEW.NAME, SNAME = :NEW.SNAME, GENDER = :NEW.GENDER, DATEBORN = :NEW.DATE_BORN, PLACE_BORN = :NEW.COUNTRY, 
    PLACE_STATE = :NEW.CITY, BLOOD_TYPE = :NEW.BLOODTYPE, ID_FATHER = :NEW.FATHER_ID, ID_MOTHER = :NEW.MOTHER_ID, 
    FATHER_NAME = :NEW.FATHER_NAME, FATHER_SNAME = :NEW.FATHER_LASTNAME, MOTHER_NAME = :NEW.MOTHER_FIRSTNAME, 
    MOTHER_SNAME = :NEW.MOTHER_LASTNAME, TIL = :NEW.TIL, EMAIL = :NEW.E_MAIL, UPDATED_FROM = v_username
    WHERE PERSONAL_RECORD.BIOGR.ID = :NEW.ID_PATIENTS;
END;
```

Comment: Try the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) Statement, this way you can update the existing column or else insert a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)-Statement with something like the following:

```
MERGE INTO personal_record.biogr USING dual ON
(PERSONAL_RECORD.BIOGR.ID = :OLD.ID_PATIENTS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN    
UPDATE SET
ID = :NEW.ID_PATIENTS, NAME = :NEW.NAME, SNAME = :NEW.SNAME, GENDER = :NEW.GENDER, DATEBORN = :NEW.DATE_BORN, PLACE_BORN = :NEW.COUNTRY, 
PLACE_STATE = :NEW.CITY, BLOOD_TYPE = :NEW.BLOODTYPE, ID_FATHER = :NEW.FATHER_ID, ID_MOTHER = :NEW.MOTHER_ID, 
FATHER_NAME = :NEW.FATHER_NAME, FATHER_SNAME = :NEW.FATHER_LASTNAME, MOTHER_NAME = :NEW.MOTHER_FIRSTNAME, 
MOTHER_SNAME = :NEW.MOTHER_LASTNAME, TIL = :NEW.TIL, EMAIL = :NEW.E_MAIL, UPDATED_FROM = v_username
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (id, name, sname, ....)
VALUES (:NEW.ID_PATIENTS, :NEW.NAME, :NEW.SNAME, ...);
```

Comment: i end up doing a count(*) and declaring a counter variable, then do a if statement to see if its 0 or 1. what is better? merge or my solution?

Comment: btw, your statement is missing a ON keyword, but it looks fine to me

Comment: Where is it missing the on-part? There is one in line 1-2. Didn't know there are more needed.

Comment: it says is missing a ON keyword at line where its merge into ... What is "USING dual" for? dual table was just for getting the current db user.

Comment: Might be needing some parenthesis. Not sure, couldn't test it without the schema. Sorry. Was ment as a hint, what could be a possible solution

Comment: You have to define the `USING` part in a merge statement but you don't need any data from there as you have all necessary columns as :NEW variables already

Comment: found the problem, i was using new.id_patients value instead of old.id_patients